# How to update 2 tables using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm just wondering why still getting not correct result (0 row(s) affected)
with my update SQL. Please help I just need to update the Table A from Table B data with Price, and Size. After executing the update script I get 0 rows(s) affected. Why?

**Table A**:

```
TableAId    CountNo     Class       RoomNo      Section     Price       Sale    Size
4           1           NULL        9           B           24347000    NULL    NULL
5           1           NULL        9           C           26881000    NULL    NULL
12          1           NULL        8           B           24245000    NULL    NULL
16          1           NULL        8           A           39038000    NULL    NULL
3           1           NULL        8           C           26495370    NULL    NULL
21          1           NULL        6           D           36423000    NULL    NULL
14          1           NULL        6           C           27200000    NULL    NULL
1           1           NULL        5           C           30483000    NULL    NULL
2           1           NULL        5           D           41052330    NULL    NULL
```

**Table B**:

```
TableBId    CountNo     Class       RoomNo      Section     Transaction     Sale        Size
12          1           NULL        9           B           NULL            24347000    23800
20          1           NULL        9           C           NULL            26881000    22800
44          1           NULL        9           NULL        NULL            40079000    23100
69          1           NULL        9           D           NULL            37614000    22100
21          1           NULL        8           C           NULL            26763000    22700
28          1           NULL        8           D           NULL            37444000    22000
13          1           NULL        8           B           NULL            24245000    23700
5           1           NULL        8           A           NULL            39038000    22500
6           1           NULL        7           A           NULL            39558000    22800
```

Updated table:

```
TableAId    CountNo     Class       RoomNo      Section     Price       Sale        Size
4           1           NULL        9           B           24347000    24347000    23800
5           1           NULL        9           C           26881000    26881000    22800
12          1           NULL        8           B           24245000    24245000    23700
16          1           NULL        8           A           39038000    39038000    22500
3           1           NULL        8           C           26495370    26763000    22700
21          1           NULL        6           D           NULL        NULL        NULL
14          1           NULL        6           C           NULL        NULL        NULL
1           1           NULL        5           C           NULL        NULL        NULL
2           1           NULL        5           D           NULL        NULL        NULL
```

SQL statement:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.Sale = y.Sale,
    x.Size = y.Size
FROM TableA x
JOIN TableB y ON x.CountNo = y.CountNo 
              AND x.Class = y.Class 
              AND x.RoomNo = y.RoomNo 
              AND x.Section = y.Section
```

> (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: Because your `Class` column is NULL for all of the rows, unless [ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) is OFF (I would not recommend this normally),  you're not going to be able to join the tables. NULL does not equal anything with ANSI_NULLS ON, it's an unknown, and NULL does not equal NULL.

Answer (score 1):

try this: you need to compare null values separately

```
UPDATE x
SET 
    x.Sale = y.Sale,
    x.Size = y.Size
FROM TableA x
    JOIN TableB y 
        ON 
        x.CountNo = y.CountNo AND
        (x.Class = y.Class OR (x.Class IS NULL and y.Class IS NULL)) AND
        x.RoomNo = y.RoomNo AND
        x.Section = y.Section
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is happening because of `NULL`

```
UPDATE x
SET 
    x.Sale = y.Sale,
    x.Size = y.Size
FROM 
    TableA x
    JOIN TableB y ON x.CountNo = y.CountNo 
                AND ISNULL(x.Class,'') = ISNULL(y.Class,'') 
                AND x.RoomNo = y.RoomNo 
                AND ISNULL(x.Section,'') = ISNULL(y.Section,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `ISNULL(, )` If column is nullable

```
UPDATE x
SET 
    x.Sale = y.Sale,
    x.Size = y.Size
FROM TableA x
    JOIN TableB y 
        ON 
        ISNULL(x.CountNo, 0) = ISNULL(y.CountNo, 0) AND 
        ISNULL(x.Class, '') = ISNULL(y.Class, '') AND
        ISNULL(x.RoomNo, 0) = ISNULL(y.RoomNo, 0) AND
        ISNULL(x.Section, '') = ISNULL(y.Section, 0)
```